# Shell32.lib not found when compiling for Windows Mobile 6

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile, arm, shell32

I tried to compile a simple windows mobile 6 project which uses the SHBrowseForFolder api call. I have also included shell32.lib in the project linker dependencies. Somehow, the shell32.lib seems to be missing in the ARMv4 sdk. Is there a workaround for this?

thanks.

Comment: `SHBrowseForFolder` seems to be supported on Windows CE, but [not supported on Windows Mobile](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/0794f09c-0bf2-4dbc-950e-28bca90abbb4).

Comment: yes. that seems to be the problem. found an msdn page that said so. it suggests that we use the GetSaveFileName(&ofn) function.

Answer (score 0):

`shell32.lib` is a desktop library.  Windows CE uses `ceshell.lib`, [as stated in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453669.aspx).  I don't know if it's available in WinMo. Since the OS is customizable, and the WinMo team rewrote the entire shell, it's always possible it was omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Chris is correct. `shell32.lib` is not included in CE.

> Somehow, the shell32.lib seems to be missing in the ARMv4 sdk. Is there a workaround for this?

You will have to write your own form to do this if you really want it.